# Why measuring the execution time of a loop gives different results execution after execution?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, benchmarking

I know it's stupid, but I still have to ask this question because it's been bothering me for days.

I use a variety of methods to test, but the results vary widely.

[The execution time of a million double-int conversions is the same as empty loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627698/the-execution-time-of-a-million-double-int-conversions-is-the-same-as-empty-loop)

Comment: You should not use a "new" question to bump an old one.

Comment: @PeterB It is not the same question. It is another question that refer to a code in another question for sure. So it respects the how to ask rules, I think. It seems that the question came later, so it is good that this is another question that have answers instead of editing the first question some days after to add a new question.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because it is not a duplicate at all...